# Can't host tcp based wcf service on IIS, Cannot obtain Metadata from net.tcp://localhost/TestApp2/MyService error pops up

Tags: wcf, iis, tcp, nettcpbinding

I have a simple test purpose WCF service. I'm trying to host it under IIS 7.5 ( Windows 7 ) but no luck so far. I'm getting error

> Cannot obtain Metadata from net.tcp://localhost/TestApp2/MyService

I have a web site TestApp2 under Default Web Site, I enabled tcp on Default Web Site and TestApp2. Here is my web.config file, while I realize that this error simply states that I didn't have endpoint for metadata exchange, I can't see what's the problem because I included endpoint for metadata exchange.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="MyService">

    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/TestApp2/MyService"
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="PortSharingBinding"
              contract="II7WcfService.IService1" />

    <endpoint address="MEX"
              binding="mexTcpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/TestApp2/MyService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="PortSharingBinding" portSharingEnabled="true">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is your service isn't actually called `MyService` but rather it is in a namespace. This means your declared endpoints are not getting picked up, and the default ones (which doesn't include `IMetadataExchange`) are being used instead.

Add the name of your namespace to the attribute in the config and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for reply Richard, MyService is svc file, that has only ServiceHost declaration in it's markup

`<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="IIS7HostedWCFService.Service1" %>`

So as you can see no namespace exists. Service1 is the .cs file which is implementation of my contract ( IService1 ). So should I change something ?

Comment: The service name is `IIS7HostedWCFService.Service1` - put that in the config file instead of MyService

Comment: I fix it finally, the problem was my svc and ServiceContract implementations had different names. Thanks Richard !